# gettings spellfiles in vim

Tags: vim, spell-checking

How do I get regional spell-files for vim? I want e.g. `de_DE` as spell language. The help suggests using http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/dictionary but I don't get how to create a spell file from them. I also found https://github.com/ganwell/vim-hunspell-dicts but the instructions don't help either.

Answer (score 2):

Vim helpfully includes the [`spellfile.vim`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#spellfile%2evim) plugin to automatically download missing spellfiles:

```
:set spelllang=de_DE
:set spell
Cannot find spell file for "de" in utf-8
Do you want me to try downloading it?
(Y)es, [N]o: Y
Downloading de.utf-8.spl...
:!curl 'http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/spell/de.utf-8.spl' -o '/tmp/vRnqpoy/2.spl'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
"/tmp/vRnqpoy/2.spl" [noeol] 5996L, 2388148C
In which directory do you want to write the file:
1. /home/martin/.vim/spell
[C]ancel, (1): 1
"~/.vim/spell/de.utf-8.spl" [New] 5996L, 2388149C written
```

If this doesn't work for you then try using `:verbose set spell` to see why the plugin isn't downloading anything.