# Vim doesnt recognize german text when spelling

Tags: vim, spell-checking, hunspell

Using Vim8 with german hunspell files.

Created german dictionary file using this command from within Vim:

```
mkspell ~/.vim/spell/de /usr/share/hunspell/de_AT.aff
```

This resulted in some error messages `Unrecognized flags in /usr/share/hunspell/de_AT.aff line xxx: ...`

The dictionary file size in ~/.vim/spell is

```
15437 Dez 14 13:58 de.utf-8.spl
```

Activating german spell checking using

```
:setlocal spell spelllang=de
```

However every word is identified to be spelled wrong and the vim command `z=` results in the error message `Sorry, no suggestions`

How can I enable spell checking using german hunspell dictionary files using vim?

Comment: Did you try using the spell files that Vim automatically downloads? That seems easier to me. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40583471/660921).

Answer (score 1):

Vim can download dictionary files on usage. This works fine for English or other simple languages but the results will be wanting for eg. German. In the case of spell checking German, download the appropriate files from http://1042.ch/spell/, save them to `~/.vim/spell/` and load them with

```
set spell spelllang=hun-de-DE-frami
```

Either replace the spelllang with the filename you downloaded or rename the downloaded files to something simpler like de.utf-8.spl